# libMagicWand.so Cannot open shared object [CODEIGNITER]

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have an error in my website using CodeIgniter like:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea- 
php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - libMagickWand.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No 
such file or directory

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

But this happens sometimes. why? how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix : Edit INDEX.PHP and change environment to "Production" from "Development".

Details: This is related to your webserver. If you're a server admin, try checking php.ini for duplicate module specially imgaick.